# Вывод в Memo и ввод в Edit

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить некоторые проблемы при роботе с формой. 
На форме в Memo при нажатии клавиши генерируется массив 10 случайных чисел. Как сделать, чтоб массив появлялся только один раз, а не при каждом нажатии?

```
procedure TForm1.Memo1Change(Sender: TObject);
var a: Tarr;
    i: integer;
    str: string;
begin
    if memchange then
        exit;

     memchange := true;
     randomize;

     str := '';
     for i := 1 to 10 do begin
         a[i] := random(10);
         str := str + inttostr(a[i]) + '  ';
     end;

     Memo1.Lines.Add(str);
     memchange := false;
end;
```

Еще на форме должны быть два компонента `edit`, в которые пользователь после получения массива  должен ввести: число (индекс элемента), которое рассчитывается по формуле `(low(array)+high(array)) div 2` (первый edit), т.е. индекс `4`; число - значение этого элемента (второй edit). И в случае, если пользователь не прав, указать на ошибку и попросить повторить попытку. Не могу сообразить, как именно это реализовать. Сделал на проверку индекса, но ничего не происходит.

```
procedure TForm3.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
  procedure CheckPivot(var a: Tarr);
  var pivot, pivoted: integer;
  begin
      pivot := (low(a) + high(a)) div 2;
      pivoted := strtoint(Edit1.Text);
      if pivot <> pivoted then
          ShowMessage('Неверно');

      Edit1.SetFocus;
  end;
begin   
end;
```

Comment: Что Вас не устраивает в первом фрагменте кода?

Comment: @Igor, массив будет появляться столько раз, сколько пользователь будет нажимать на клавиатуре, можно ли сделать так, чтоб генерировать массив можно было только один раз, то есть при последующих нажатиях не создавался новый массив?

Comment: уберите строчку  `memchange := false;`

Comment: 1. Возможно вам подойдет событие OnCreate формы. Отработает только один раз при старте. А для Memo установить свойство `ReadOnly:=true`
2. Массив `a` объявлен в методе `Memo1Change`, каким образом Вы получаете к нему доступ для вызова `CheckPivot`